# How make my angular 2 application more responsive with Rich UI

Tags: angular

I am creating an angular application and I'm using *Springboot* for backend API's with *postgresql* database.

I need to make my application fully featured as well as responsive with Rich UI.

I have searched for many modules and packages that can help to build my angular2 app. I got some of them, such as; `ngx permissionsModule`, `angular-simple-ui` module, `angular2-permissions` module, etc.

So how can my application get facilitated from angular side?

Which features of angular should i use for my applications?

Please suggest me some key points to elaborate the angular2 side.

Comment: This question is opinion based and should not belong here. But if I can give you a piece of advice, you should take a look at `@angular/material` and `@angular/flex-layout`. Those are two NPM packages that will greatly improve your Angular experience.

Comment: thank-you. Surely i will check

Comment: when i searched about @angular/flex-layout, there was mention that "requires Angular v4.1 or higher." But i am having application using angular2.

Comment: Then use Angular 5. Update your application, because packages evolve with Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all depends on your project requirement. If your client will like material UI then go for it. 
If your client likes Bootstrap then go with bootstrap and Prime-Ng.

Comment: Actually mainly we are focusing on Bootstraping. so can you suggest another packages for that.

Comment: Then go with simple bootstrap. There is also a package that do the same as bootstrap do with jquery. Link https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home